# Do eigenvectors of a block matrix span?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, independence, block-matrices

Assume I have an $n\times n$ block matrix of the form $M=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ -B & A\end{pmatrix}$ and it has $n$ independent eigenvectors. Note here that $A$ and $B$ are square matrices (of the same size).

I can see that $\begin{pmatrix}\vec{v} \\ i\vec{v}\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector when $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $A+iB.$ I can also see that $\begin{pmatrix}\vec{w} \\ -i\vec{w}\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector when $\vec{w}$ is an eigenvector of $A-iB.$

However, these two vectors are only orthogonal when $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ are orthogonal.

So if I find these $n$ eigenvectors, under what conditions will they be independent?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over some field, then $A$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors if and only if $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're giving me a hint. This isn't a homework problem. I'm far too old for that lol

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't currently have the time to think of and write a full answer so I thought the hint could've been a good place to start. Matrices of this type are not necessarily diagonalizable, you can take $A=B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ as an example. This means you need stronger conditions for $A$ and $B$ so that there will exist such $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't mean to sound unappreciative. I really am thankful for your help and your hint.

In any case, while I see the truth of your statement, the $A$ and $B$ you are suggesting would not lead to an $M$ with $n$ independent eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes, those values of $A$ and $B$ were meant to be a counterexample. I'm a little bit stumped by this question though, I hope somebody can provide necessary and sufficient conditions for $n$ such vectors to exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the answer to this question. If you normalize these vectors and put them in as columns to some matrix $U,$ this matrix will be unitary. Further, because the matrices that I end up with are Hermitian (a property that happens to be true of the problem I'm working on), all of the vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ span and thus we have linear independence.